# Show / Hide administration menu (module)

Tags: 7, javascript, routes

Is it possible to use a javascript function for a link in Drupal?
I would like to make an option to show/hide the administration menu when clicked on the Drupal icon.
Something simple like this:

```
  $links['icon'] = array(
    '#title' => theme('admin_menu_icon'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('admin-menu-icon')),
    '#href' => 'javascript: alert("ok")', 
    '#options' => array(
      'html' => TRUE,
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple... Just found it myself :)

```
'#attributes' => array('onmousedown' => array('alert("ok")')),
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made a small module to show/hide the administration module when clicking on the Drupal icon. Sometimes the menu bar is just anoying me ;)

```
function mymodule_init() {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/adminmenu.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));
}

function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    if (!empty($theme_registry['admin_menu_icon'])) {
        $theme_registry['admin_menu_icon']['function'] = 'mymodule_admin_menu_icon';
    }
}

function mymodule_admin_menu_icon($variables) {
  return '<img onmousedown="jQuery(\'#admin-menu\').toggleClass(\'collapsed\')" class="admin-menu-icon" src="' . $variables['src'] . '" width="16" height="16" title="Show / Hide" alt="Show / Hide" />';
}
```

And the CSS part:

```
#admin-menu.collapsed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```